# How to view to user only the node that referenced to him?

Tags: views, users, entities, nodes

I have a Content Type with a user reference field.

I want that the user can display\access only to the nodes that referenced to him.

Can I do this with Views?

I already tried the modules **Node access user reference** and **Node access node reference** with no success because they have a huge bug. When the module is enabled many View becomes inaccessible ( https://www.drupal.org/node/1311460 ).

Comment: If you are willing to use the entity references and rules modules instead which could both be very beneficial elsewhere, there could be an easy solution. I don't wanna force either on ya so let me know.

Comment: @Niall Murphy : I'm willing to use entity reference and rules but how I can to do it? I cannot to set the rules condition and rules action.

Comment: Solution added below.. Let me know if ya have any trouble with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Reference and Rules Solution.

1. Install both modules
2. Add an entity reference field with unlimited values to your content type. Make sure it references users.
3. For views, create a content view and add a contextual filter for the field you created. My test contextual filter was called `Content: User Ref Test`. Your contextual filter will have the same name as the field you created.
4. In the contextual filter's settings, click `Provide Default: User ID from logged in User`. This will only show content where the user has been referenced.
5. To make the content safe from typing in the url, create a `Content is Viewed` rule for that content type.
6. In the conditions, choose "list contains item". The list is the entity reference field and the item is the logged in user. At the bottom of the condition, you then negate the rule. It should look like `NOT Item in List "Parameter: List: [node:field-user-ref-test], Item: [site:current-user]`
7. Add a second data comparison condition that allows the admin (or you could do this by user role) to view the content. Negate this condition as well. `NOT Data Comparison > Parameter: Data to compare: [site:current-user:uid], Data value: 1`
8. Add a system redirect to the homepage and a message explaining why the user couldn't view the content.

If it doesn't work, check to make sure the entity reference field is set to unlimited because that's why we use the list in rules.

Comment: Note that you can use a normal filter **User: Current** instead of a contextual filter.

Comment: That's in a user view. You have to use a contextual filter in a content view.

Comment: No, if you have the relationship to the user, you can use a normal filter selecting that relationship.

Comment: Ha, yea. I checked the filter list before adding the relationship.

Comment: Thank you @Niall Murphy but if my reference field is set to 1 value, can I use `NOT Data Comparison instead` of `NOT Item in List "Parameter"`?

Comment: **EDIT**: Use `NOT Data Comparison instead` seems to work as I expected. :-) - A small note, can this solution create security problems?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but for full security, you should implement the idea of the rule into a custom module I guess.

Comment: @kb8 If you want the most secure access control, you should really go with the solution I posted using access grants. The rules can only prevent it if the user tries to view the node and It won't prevent the user to see the title of the node in any listing, which is an information disclosure. On the other side, using access grants, the node won't even be listed in views results if the user isn't granted to view the node. So the user won't ever see the title of the node.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using views, following the steps to display only the nodes referencing the current user:

1. Add a **relationship** to your field: **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity** *A bridge to the User entity that is referenced via field_your_reference_field*
2. Add a filter criteria **User: Current** and select as **Relationship** the newly added relationship, which should be automatically selected if you don't have any other relationships in your view. Select the radio button **Yes**.

UPDATE:

As I read your question again, I saw you want to restrict the access, as well. There are many ways to achieve that. You may do that with Rules or using node access grants `hook_node_access_records()` and `hook_node_grants()`.
If you need instructions on how to use node access grants, I can improve my answer. Otherwise, the solution with rules is already described by [Niall Murphy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/190313/10176).

#### UPDATE 2: Using node access grants

If you choose to use node access grants, then you don't need to do above filter on views. Since, views already respects the node access grants and filters the nodes readily.

You need to implement two functions in your custom module: [`hook_node_access_records()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7) and [`hook_node_grants()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access_records().
 */
function YOURMODULE_node_access_records($node) {
  $grants = array();
  if ($node->type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {
    $referenced_uid = $node->field_your_reference_field['und'][0]['target_id'];
    $grants[] = array(
      'realm' => 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_referenced_user', // The naming of the realm is up to you.
      'gid' => $referenced_uid,
      'grant_view' => 1,
      'grant_update' => 0,
      'grant_delete' => 0,
    );
  }

  return $grants;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_grants().
 */
function YOURMODULE_node_grants($account, $op) {
  $grants['YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_referenced_user'] = array($account->uid);

  return $grants;
}
```

Explanation of the above code:

The first function is called on saving the node and puts the node into a realm named `YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_referenced_user` and gives it a Grant Id as the referenced user's uid.

Second function is called on every page call, so it is important not to do any heavy calculations on this part. This function gives the user the grant Id same as his user Id on the same realm. So that this user can view all nodes in that realm with a Grant Id equals to his user Id.

Comment: The rule is stop users from viewing the node anyway.

Comment: As I read the question again, I noticed that 'access' word :)

Comment: The solution of Niall seems work well but I'm open to know node access grants. This I could serve afterwards.

Comment: @kb8 I updated my answer an included a working example of how to implement node grants to control the access.

Answer (score 0):

Just add contextualy filter in it. Select option 'provide default value' and check the option, user id from logged in url. This view will give only the content uploaded by him/her.

Comment: It's not for author access.